# Extjs4: Cannot display all Tree Nodes -> TypeError: records[i] is undefined

Tags: json, tree, extjs4

I get this Error: TypeError: records[i] is undefined

I get my json from my database. The array, which I encode to json looks like this:

```
array(
['data'] =>
array(

[0] =>
    array(

['id'] =>
    1
['text'] =>
    'COUNTRY1'
['leaf'] =>
    ['children'] =>
    array(

[0] =>
    array(

['id'] =>
    'HF'
['text'] =>
    'HF'
['leaf'] =>
)
[1] =>
    array(

['id'] =>
    'TF'
['text'] =>
    'TF'
['leaf'] =>
)
[2] =>
    array(

['id'] =>
    'SF'
['text'] =>
    'SF'
['leaf'] =>
)
)
)
[1] =>
    array(

['id'] =>
    2
['text'] =>
    'COUNTRY2'
['leaf'] =>
    ['children'] =>
    array(

[0] =>
    array(

['id'] =>
    'HF'
['text'] =>
    'HF'
['leaf'] =>
)
[1] =>
    array(

['id'] =>
    'TF'
['text'] =>
    'TF'
['leaf'] =>
)
[2] =>
    array(

['id'] =>
    'SF'
['text'] =>
    'SF'
['leaf'] =>
)
[3] =>
    array(

['id'] =>
    'SP'
['text'] =>
    'SP'
['leaf'] =>
)
)
)
```

My store looks like this:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Trees', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
model: "Tree",
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url : 'data/ajax.tree.php',
    extraParams:{
        action:'getTree'
    },
    actionMethods: {
        create : 'POST',
        read   : 'POST',
        update : 'POST',
        destroy: 'POST'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    }
}
});
```

I can only open the first Node "COUNTRY1". All the subparty were shown. But when i click on the next node, the Error appears.

Why do I get this Error? Can someone Help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the same leaf (with the same id) shows up in multiple branches. ExtJS tree does not handle that. either don't bring the id or customize the ids to be unique in the entire tree.